# Loading images by Glide spoil image quality

Tags: android, image, gallery, android-glide, image-quality

I build simple gallery. I load my photos using Glide. It looks like on images loaded by glide is some kind of streak (pixels seems to be visible). 
I tried to load photo with changed Format `RGB_565/ARGB_8888` and I used `.dontTransform()` but still it looks worse than original photo.

Code I use to load :

```
ImageView photoDetails;
photoDetails = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageDetails);
Glide.with(this)
        .load(pictureFile) //path to picture
        .asBitmap()
        .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
        .dontTransform()
        .into(photoDetails);
```

Comment: Please paste xml code of imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the original image using `Glide` I use the code below:

```
  Glide.with(view.getContext())
                    .load(pictureFile)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL,Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        }
                    });
```

Remember that the picture in browser may look different on the device due to the screen resolution of your device. Using this method you will be able to check the pixels using the  `Bitmap` object.
Also, keep in mind that your `ImageView` must have `width` and `height` with `WRAP_CONTENT` value.

Comment: It works a quite better but eat so much RAM thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this one**:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
```

Imageview property set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`